# How to get a widget to run with multiple actions from typoscript?

Tags: widget, typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-9.x

In creating a new uncached widget for login/logout/registering users in the Frontend, am unable to get it to work. How can I call two different controllers from typoscript (see code below)?

Am using TYPO3 9.5. Knowing how to create one is important because I'll need that info in creating many others for various uses. I have previously created a complex login system without widget/controller/action in TYPO3.

In `ext_localconf.php`, there is;

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    VendorName.ExtensionName, 
    PluginName, 
    [
    'Frontend' => 'index',
    'Account' => 'index,login,logout,register'
], [
    'Account' => 'login,logout,register'
]);
```

Under folder structure `Classes/Controller` there is class `VendorName\ExtensionName\Controller\AccountController` which has;

```
class AccountController extends AbstractWidgetController {

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $supportedRequestTypes = [
        Request::class,
        WidgetRequest::class
    ];


    public function initializeAction() {

    }

    public function indexAction() {

    }

    public function loginAction() {

        return $this->view->assign('raw', 'Hello World');
    }

    public function logoutAction() {

    }

    public function registerAction() {

    }


    /**
     * Handles a request. The result output is returned by altering the given response.
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\RequestInterface $request The request object
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\ResponseInterface $response The response, modified by this handler
     *
     * @return void
     * @api
     */
    public function processRequest(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response) {

        #ActionController::processRequest($request, $response);
    }
}
```

And in the ts file there is;

```
page = PAGE
page {
    ...

    10 = USER
    10 {
        ...

        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        vendorName = VendorName
        extensionName = ExtensionName
        pluginName = PluginName

    }
}

...

5 = USER_INT
5 {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    vendorName = VendorName
    extensionName = ExtensionName
    pluginName = PluginName
    controller = Account
    action = login
}
```

When running this code, the PAGE ts produces the page using the Frontend controller index action which returns raw html through a fluid template. But when I add the USER_INT part, TYPO3 runs out of memory and displays a blank page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Widgets are a type of ViewHelper used in Fluid templates. From what you describe, I think you want a plugin. Your Controller class needs to extend `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController`, not `TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Widget\Controller\AbstractWidgetController` for that.

Comment: Thanks for response. Am actually trying something similar to extension sr_langauge_menu. You see, it displays a menu upon which one can change the site language. But in my case the login should be uncached coz it is supposed to change upon login.

Comment: So I tried changing the controller to Action Controller but still not working.

Comment: Am actually not getting any error. I dove into the TYPO3 code yesterday to check why this wasn't working, and found something very interesting. Values from TypoScript were not being picked up (and they should). So if you have two calls for bootstrap from TypoScript and both assigned controller and action, the controller and action gets ignored and results in an endless loop. Will write to TYPO3 forge see if this is by design or was overlooked during TYPO3 9.5 development. But thanks alot for your help. I appreciated it.